# CRC Arduino - Simple implementation for Sanity test

Tags: arduino, checksum, crc

I'm sending command and parameters from one arduino board to another one. I want to validate whether the data has been corrupted or not at the other end. I'm looking for a basic sanity validation.

My packet looks like

```
struct Command {
   uint8_t id,
   uint8_t action,
   int param
}
```

How would I go about creating CRC to validate at the other end? Thanks.

Comment: So the total message size is either 4 bytes (if int is 2 bytes) or 6 bytes (if int is 4 bytes)?  If so, then an 8 bit CRC is probably good enough, assuming the bit error rate is low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example:

```
unsigned crc8_koop(unsigned crc, unsigned char const *data, size_t len) {
    if (data == NULL)
        return 0;
    crc = ~crc & 0xff;
    while (len--) {
        crc ^= *data++;
        for (unsigned k = 0; k < 8; k++)
            crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0xb2 : crc >> 1;
    }
    return crc ^ 0xff;
}
```

Call with `data` equal to `NULL` to get the initial CRC value.

Comment: So from my example; If I have Command* comm, then should I be calling crc8_koop(initialCRC, &comm->id, 3) ? I have 3 types in my Command struct, and each would be 1 byte when converted to unsigned char.

Comment: No, you need the number of bytes, not the number of things. Use `sizeof(struct command)` to get the number of bytes in your structure. (Probably 6.) So `crc8_koop(crc8_koop(0, NULL, 0), &comm->id, sizeof(struct Command))`. That is assuming that you transmit the structure as is. If you, for example, send the `int` as one or two bytes instead of four bytes, then you will need to process that separately to make sure you get the correct bytes to avoid endianess issues.

Comment: I was assuming that since they're converted to unsigned char, it'd be 3 bytes for the 3 items. When I do sizeof(comm->...), I get 1 for the two uint8_t , and 2 for an int. So, that's 4. So, essentially I could add another variable in the struct that holds the CRC, and then when I'd pass 4 as len, then it would calculate CRC for the first 3 elements? Is it how it works?. Pardon my naivety.

Comment: You are sending a message somehow, either sending bytes individually or assembling the bytes into a buffer that is sent. You simply run the exact bytes that you send through the CRC. Then send the resulting CRC byte. Repeat on the other end to check the message.

Comment: I worked out the internal calculations. So if I understand correctly, the internal implementation is a randomized function, right?

Comment: There's nothing random about it. The calculation is entirely deterministic.

Comment: Sorry for my choice of word, I understand it's totally deterministic. I wanted to confirm if the operation you choose for the implementation were random (did the choice of operation ensured there are no bad case scenario?). It already looks more than good enough for my use-case. Just double checking.

Comment: What operation did I choose?

Comment: I might be creating more confusion here. I meant the complement, shifts and the XORs.

Comment: Ah, you mean the definition of the CRC. I chose the CRC of an empty message to be zero just because that makes sense. I chose the initial register value to be non-zero, so that a message of all zeros doesn't always end up as zero, regardless of its length. (All one's is a common choice.) I chose a reflected CRC, since the shift down implementation is a little more efficient. I chose the polynomial based on [Koopman's research into CRC polynomials](https://users.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/crc/).

Comment: Perfect. I'll take a look at that. Thanks for the links and your patience on this. Appreciate it.